# UdpClient constructor throws SocketException NotInitialized

Tags: c#, socketexception, udpclient

Sporadically, the UdpClient constructors throw a SocketException, with SocketErrorCode=**NotInitialized** and ErrorCode=10093 (**WSANOTINITIALISED**).

I tried the default constructor:

```
udpClient = new UdpClient();
```

and also the constructor providing the listening endpoint:

```
udpClient = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort));
```

I call this constructor inside a thread, but this thread is only started once. I only call the `.Close()` method at the end of the application.

The exception is not always thrown, just sporadically. I haven't found a pattern. When it happens, if I retry to construct it again, it throws the same error.

I am using the .NET Framework 4.8, the problem happens on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

What can be the reason? How can I solve/workaround this? Thanks!

Comment: Another connection is using the same port number.  Check frm cmd.exe >Netstat -a and see if the port is being used.

Comment: Is not the case, I tested and that would return the SocketErrorCode "AddressAlreadyInUse" instead.

Comment: The user may not own the socket : Successful WSAStartup not yet performed.
Either the application has not called WSAStartup or WSAStartup failed. The application may be accessing a socket that the current active task does not own (that is, trying to share a socket between tasks), or WSACleanup has been called too many times.

Comment: The problem was other c++ unmanaged library was handling WSAStartup and WSACleanup incorrectly. After fixing this library to initialize WSAStartup once at startup and call WSACleanup only when the application is terminated, the SocketException disappeared. Without having sources of the libraries used, it would be tricky to diagnose this kind of errors.